# how to hide the Volume control when i show video controls on html5?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video

I using video on my html page and i set the video controls to be shown. 
But i want to hide the Volume controler on my video.

I just want that the user will see only the scrollbar.
I can't find any way to do it.

Answer (score 6):

If you're targetting webkit, you could use the following rules:

```
video::-webkit-media-controls-volume-slider {  display: none; }

video::-webkit-media-controls-mute-button {  display: none; }
```